Does code require clearance between drain pipes and cabinetry?
The plumber for our builder installed a p trap that has zero clearance to the cabinet floor  in our kitchen. It is leaking. You can not even put a piece of paper between the trap and the cupboard floor.  Is this a legal installation in Virginia?

does the joint slide?

Asking your local building department is the way to go.  There is a national plumbing code, but state and/or local town/city/county might be a bit different.

I know of no code that states that there MUST be clearance between the bottom of the p-trap and the cabinet bottom. Traps are set so as to fit properly to the drain in the wall.  Is this causing a problem, or do you just not like it?

It is causing a problem...water leak at the pvc nut..can't tell if cabinet base damaged and can't completely clean up from the keak

Solar Mike...no it does not slide

Get the plumber back if it is leaking.  It is the plumber's job to make sure their work does not leak.  They should not be paid to fix their mistake, plus repairing any damage.  Common cabinets use wood like products that do not like getting wet.  About the same as the gremlins movie.

@Mickey, I edited the pertinent info about the leak into your post.  Yes the plumber should be called back to repair properly.

If it's jammed agaist the cabinet floor, it's possible it's slipped onto the tailpiece crooked.  Or is the problem that the drain into the wall is too low for the P-trap?  Some pics would sure help your case here...

Unfortunately the builder is the plumbing contractor for my home.

There are no "clearances" specified by plumbing codes for pipes or their fittings.

That said, they can't be tight to framing or cabinetry or they tend to creak with thermal expansion. I'm not sure whether that's addressed in code, but it's a requirement in my opinion.

I have pictures but don't know how to add them...going to my local county office with the pics.
